# How can I change a value by a calculation in a csv file with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

I've got this csv file (which has no header) :

```
001;0
002;7
003;192
004;72
```

Using powershell (for automation purpose), **I need to decrement by 1 the value of the second column**, so the output should be this :

```
001;-1
002;6
003;191
004;71
```

I can't find any solution without adding a header to the file (which is done with [this code](https://pastebin.com/7kf1wSd8)).

Below is where I am currently, struggling between the two pipes.

```
$input = "input.csv"
$output = "output.csv"

Import-CSV $input |  | Export-CSV -Path $output -NoTypeInformation
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `$input` as self-defined variable, because it is an [Automatic Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input) in PowerShell.

This could be a way of achieving what you want:

```
$inputFile  = "input.csv"
$outputFile = "output.csv"

$result = switch -Wildcard -File $inputFile {
    '*;*' {
        $item, $value = $_ -split ';', 2
        '{0};{1}' -f $item, ([int]$value - 1)
    }
}
$result | Set-Content -Path $outputFile
```

Resulting file:

> ```
> 001;-1
> 002;6
> 003;191
> 004;71
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It's one line only:

```
$file = 'path to .csv'

Get-Content $file | % { $x = $_ -split ';'; $y = (([int]($x[1]))-1).ToString(); "$($x[0]);$($y)"; }
```